# Trying to connect C program to phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, c, phpmyadmin, arduino

I've been trying to successfully connect my Arduino to my phpMyAdmin server but I haven't been able to. The Arduino has some Ultrasonic sensors connected (to measure distance) and for some reason not all the values are being sent to the server. I shouldn't be as complicated.

So each sensor has its own id, measured distance, and a level where the sensor is located.

The id is to identify the sensor (duh!) but for some reason all I'm getting is 0 for this value which I think is because it's only reading the values of the first sensor (with id 0).

So let me show you my code, this is the method that repeats, I think that my mistake is not being able to send the information multiple times, like separating the information from each sensor and it only send the first 4 values and that's what it displays on the data base.

```
void loop(){

  int distance;

  //=======

  for (uint8_t i = 0; i < SONAR_NUM; i++) {   

    if( cm[i] > 10 || cm[i]==0){

      distance = cm [i];//delete if no 
    }
    else{
      distance = cm[i];
      //Serial.println(distance);


    }
  }

  for (uint8_t i = 0; i < SONAR_NUM; i++) {
    if (millis() >= pingTimer[i]) {
      pingTimer[i] += PING_INTERVAL * SONAR_NUM;
      if (i == 0 && currentSensor == SONAR_NUM - 1)
        sonar[currentSensor].timer_stop();
      currentSensor = i;
      cm[currentSensor] = 0;

      sonar[currentSensor].ping_timer(echoCheck);
    }
    //client.stop();
  }

  //===================================================
  if(client.connect(serverName, 80) )
  {
    //Serial.println("Connected");
    if (client.connected()){
      delay(100);
      //Serial.println("Client is available, CONNECTED!");
      //client.print( "GET /add.php?distance=");
     ////////////// 
     int lvl = 0;
  for (uint8_t i = 0; i < SONAR_NUM; i++) {
    if(i<2)
      lvl = 1;
    else if (i>1 && i<3)
      lvl =2;
     else
       lvl = 3;

     Serial.print("SPOT: ");
     client.print( "GET /sendfromarduino.php?sensorID=");
     Serial.print(i);
     client.print (i);

     Serial.print(" DISTANCE: ");
     Serial.print(cm[i]);
     distance = cm[i];
     client.print( "&value=");
     client.print(distance);
     Serial.print("cm ");

     Serial.print(" LEVEL: ");
     client.print( "&level=");
     Serial.print (lvl);
     client.print (lvl);


  }
  Serial.println(); 
  //////////////////////////////////////
//      Serial.print("Distance: ");
//      client.print(distance);
//      Serial.println(distance);
      client.println( "HTTP/1.1");
      client.println( "Host: test.testserver.com" );
      client.println( "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" );
      client.println();
      client.println();
      client.stop();
    }
    else
    {
      //Serial.println(distance);
      Serial.println("Connection Failed");
    }
  }
  delay(100);
}
```

and then here is the code for the PHP file that should be perfectly ok according to my knowledge and past experience:

```
<?php


        $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test_alpha;charset=UTF-8', 'test_alpha', 'testtest');
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

        $sensorID = intval($_GET['i']);
        //$time = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
        $value = intval($_GET['distance']);
        $level = intval($_GET['lvl']);


        $sql = "INSERT INTO `pspace`(`sensorID`, `time`, `value`, `level`) VALUES ('$sensorID',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'$value','$level')";

        $stmt = $db->query($sql);
        //echo json_encode(array('spaces'=>$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)));

    ?>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does it print all the correct info to the serial port? that'd be the first place to troubleshoot, if it doesn't get out of the arduino your PHP is out of the question. If it does, then have the php dump everything to a file to see if the data it gets is valid.

Comment: @sachleen Yeah, it is printing all of the information correctly to the serial port, but when it comes to the client, it doesn't. How do I make the php dump everything to a file?

Comment: I would print the `GET` code to serial exactly as you are trying to print it to the Ethernet client, and then try to execute the request on a PC, just to make sure your query is formatted correctly.

Comment: Sanity check: what is `SONAR_NUM` defined as?  And where is it defined?  Also as written, your first conditional does the same thing when both `true` and `false`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where it says `if (client.connected())`

It should be `while (client.connected())`

Problem solved! Thanks to everyone who dedicated time to my question!